# how to internally load balance multiple instances of web/worker roles in Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure

In Azure, I have a webrole exposed to public and 2 workerroles only accessible within the private network. Now I want to internally load balance the workerroles, so I have set an internal endpoint for workerroles, but what address should I use to communicate to the workers, it can't be the internal IP address because it's specific to a particular instance and wouldn't go through the load balancer right?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no internal load balancer in Windows Azure. The only load balancer is the one that has the public IP Addresses.

If you want to load balance only internal addresses (workers) you have to maintain it yourself. Meaning you have to install some kind of a load balancer on Azure VM, which is part of the same VNet. That load balancer may be of your choice (Windows or Linux). And you have to implement a watchdog service for when topology changes - i.e. workers are being recycled, hardware failure, scaling events. I would not recommend this approach unless this is absolutely necessary.

Last option is to have a (cached) pool of IP Endpints of all the workers and randomly chose one when you need.

Comment: hmm, the 1st option seems too much for me,the 2nd option, "randomly" means the service would randomly fail when one or more instance(s) stop working.I think it's better leave it to Microsoft for now.

Comment: second option means that you have to keep the pool up to date at interval of your will. And yes, there might be times when it fails, but it might be neglect able depending on the period you choose to update the pool. Plus, you can use the [RoleEnvironemnt.Changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changed.aspx) event to forcibly update the pool of Endpoints when something changes in the Environement (scaling/recycling/healing/etc.).

Comment: ahha, more clear now, thanks, I will do some research then have a go!

Answer (score 1):

Azure based Internal Load Balancers (ILB) are available as of TUESDAY, MAY 20, 2014.

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/20/internal-load-balancing/

Can be used for SQL AlwaysON deployments and publishing and internal endpoint accessible accessible from your VNET only (i.e not public routable).

note: Searching for ILB help and spotted this thread. Thought it was worth updating , if not let me know and I will delete.

Comment: You should give this a shot and update your answer.  Despite the documentation saying it is possible, I cannot make it work.  The error I see is, "This operation cannot be performed on a deployment containing web or worker roles."

Comment: Currently working on a project to deploy ILB on a Worker Role for UDP/TCP. I also saw  "This operation cannot be performed on a deployment containing web or worker roles" message. Resolution is to updated to the latest version of the Azure SDK (2.5) in my case. Will post an update if this resolves. Likely be a couple of weeks until I have the time. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure IIS of your `WebRole` to act as `Reverse Proxy` for you using `Application Request Routing` then configure it's rules to Load-Balance requests using your chosen algorithm.

The easiest way will be to modify your `WebRole.cs` to obtain the list of (internal) endpoints of your `WorkerRole` then add it programatically (see example [here](http://coderead.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/using-iis-application-request-routing-to-load-balance-on-azure/)).

Alternatively, you can use a Startup-Script to invoke `appcmd` to achieve the same results.

Lastly, you'll have to change your client settings to point requests to the (proxied) IIS endpoint instead of the regular WorkerRole endpoints.

Comment: Just configuring the ARR once doesn't do the trick. You have to implement a `watchdog` functionality to monitor for `RoleEnvironment.Changed` and reconfigure the ARR on all role instances accordingly. Everything this is achieved via the [SessionAffinity](https://github.com/richorama/AzurePluginLibrary/tree/master/plugins/SessionAffinity) plugin. Better description how it works you can find [here](http://blogs.staykov.net/2013/07/sessionaffinity-plugin-for-windows-azure.html). Note that this plugin only works for WorkerRoles and not for WebRoles. I have to work on a version for WebRoles.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Azure now supports Internal Load Balancing (ILB).

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/20/internal-load-balancing